# Dynamically import SASS files via React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I have to make interface suitable with two different color themes - light and dark. Color theme is being selected by user via button/switch/whatever.

The problem (as I think) is that my React application is being bundled via Webpack, so all my SASS-compiled styles is being embedded into the main HTML template as `<style>...</style>` (each `style` tag references to its SASS-file). I know, that I can assign some class name to app wrapper and then write nested style for every selector that needs to be recolorized. But it is not such productive as, for example, import necessary SASS file depending on what color theme was selected by user.

Is there any way to solve this problem in a better way?

Comment: One idea would be to add a class to the App wrapper component specifying what theme to use.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana edited. I meant it under "assign some style to app wrapper".

Comment: use css modules + code split